# How to encrypt the pdf format

Tags: asp.net

hai friends
i am sending pdf attachment mail through the vb.net program .it will go and save in the mail. i want to encrypt and send this pdf. if user open that pdf document trough the it should ask username/password and allow it save local system how to achieve this.Pls its urgent.....

Comment: that wont be possible i think so.... You can send a link to that mail ask them to enter name and password and make them download the pdf...

Comment: You can add a password directly to a pdf, but not a username. Are you creating the PDF yourself? How to password protect it will be specific to the creation method. An alternative would be a password-protected zip file.

Comment: yes i am creating a pdf it save in the local system and also i will send that file to the concern usernames mail id if he opens it should ask user

Answer (score 2):

If you really need a username/password combination, it may be easier to zip the file up prior to sending it. For example,

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com

Comment: and if you deliver over SSL then it's encrypted to the user's desktop